# Back key closing all the activities registered in the task

Tags: java, android, android-activity, task

My application uses differents activities to do what I want it to do. The behaviour I am looking for is the complete closure of the application, with each and every activity present in the task being closed, when the back key is pressed.

Is this possible? If yes, how can I do?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this behavior in every activity, then when each activity starts another (by calling `startActivity()`), have it then call `finish()`. That will remove it from the back stack. That way, there is only one activity for your app at any time, and when when the user presses the back key, it will finish and your app will exit.

Answer (score 1):

this code may help you:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(yourcurrentactivityname.this).setTitle(
    "Attention").setMessage(
    "Want to exit ?")
    .setPositiveButton("YES",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("NO",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {

                }
            }).show();
    return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

    //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Comment: That will finish the current activity only.

Comment: That will work, but it seems kind of a violent way to go about things. I'd at least stick in a call to `onPause()` for the current activity before killing the process.

Comment: If the current activity has a file open for write, an active data base connection, or anything similar that would normally be cleaned up in `onPause()`, then calling `killProcess()` may cause data corruption. That's why I suggest calling `onPause()` before calling `killProcess()` if using this approach.

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks I never thought of that.Thanks Buddy